# Binary searchtree, trying to implement a remove node method, trouble with pointers

Tags: python, pointers, binary-search-tree, nodes

I found another good thread here at stackoverflow, gonna link it [removing a node from a binary search tree using recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26568163/removing-a-node-from-a-binary-search-tree-using-recursion) . Here is where I've taken the code from, its looking like this:

```
import random
from time import time

class BinaryNode:

    def __init__(self, value = None):
        """Create binary node"""
        self.value = value
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def add(self, val):
        """Adds a new node to the tree containing this value"""
        if val <= self.value:
            if self.left:
                self.left.add(val)
            else:
                self.left = BinaryNode(val)
        else:
            if self.right:
                self.right.add(val)
            else:
                self.right = BinaryNode(val)

    def delete(self):
        """
         Remove value of self from BinaryTree. Works in conjunction with remove
         method in BinaryTree
        """

        if self.left == self.right == None:
            return None
        if self.left == None:
            return self.right
        if self.right == None:
            return self.left

        child = self.left
        grandchild = child.right
        if grandchild:
            while grandchild.right:
                child = grandchild
                grandchild = child.right
            self.value = grandchild.value
            child.right = grandchild.left
        else:
            self.left = child.left
            self.value = child.value

        return self

class BinaryTree:

    def __init__(self):
        """Create empty binary tree"""
        self.root = None

    def add(self, value):
        """Insert value into proper location in Binary Tree"""
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = BinaryNode(value)
        else:
            self.root.add(value)

    def contains(self, target):
        """Check whether BST contains target value"""

        node = self.root
        while node:
            if target == node.value:
                return True
            if target < node.value:
                node = node.left
            else:
                node = node.right

        return False

    def remove(self, value):
        """Remove value from tree"""

        if self.root:
            self.root = self.removeFromParent(self.root, value)

    def removeFromParent(self, parent, value):
        """remove value from tree rooted at parent"""
        if parent is None:
            return None

        if value == parent.value:
            return parent.delete()
        elif value < parent.value:
            parent.left = self.removeFromParent(parent.left, value)
        else:
            parent.right = self.removeFromParent(parent.right, value)

        return parent
```

If we focus on the `delete` method under the `BinaryNode` class, I need some help understand the pointers, I have put together my own binary searchtree before but I cannot understand, is `self.left` a pointer? What is `self.left.right` (see `grandchild`), is this a pointer from the "start", soon to be root, to the child, and then to right (to the grandchild). It also feels a bit weird for me that the `delete` method doesn't need an argument with which value to remove, I dont see anywhere else using that method...

Comment: why do CS instructor insist on teaching tree's in python ... it is a terrible example to use python for (its easy just a bad practical example)

Comment: The `delete` on `BinaryNode` means to delete *that node* in the tree. It's the `BinaryTree` class that walks over the tree to find out exactly which `BinaryNode` has the right value.

Comment: @JoranBeasley  Always fighting the previous war?  To be fair, every phone screen I've had with Google for Python positions included binary tree questions.  Despite me reminding them, "We don't really use trees in Python."  They're used to C and I'm quite sure trees are *critical* to what Google does in C.  Just likely not Python.

Comment: oh yeah trees are great in C/C++ (and i suppose there are probably a handful of instances where you might use them in python (although theres plenty of tree libraries for python if you really need them)) ... it just boggles my mind that professors think trees are a good exercise when teaching python ... anyway OT rant over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **left** and **right** attributes are objects.  Actually, they are implemented as object references, a.k.a. pointers.

self.left.right is the left-then-right grandchild of **self** (your temporary "root").  **self* can have up to four grandchlidren; this is the second one (counting left to right), the left child's right child.

**delete** does have an argument: **self**.  That's how it knows which node to remove.  The method isn't used elsewhere because none of the other methods need to delete a node.  You're developing a class to be used from outside, not a self-sufficient application.

Does that answer your current confusions well enough?  Try drawing out the tree -- in pencil -- and working through the methods.  Erase and redraw pointers as you step through the code.  Perhaps better, use two colors, so you have "before" and "after" pointers, and number the changes as you go along.

---

I wouldn't say that **self** acts as a sentinel node; the "sentinel" concept is more to stop iteration at a particular point.

As for the pointer/object dichotomy, I suspect that one of the reasons you're having trouble is that Python doesn't let you separate the two very often.  Every variable value is a reference to the variable object.

Specifically, self.right.left is ultimately a *reference* to the grandchild.  However, the Python run-time system uses this to give you direct access to the grandchild object.  In other words, *you* can't really tell the difference.  Think of it either way; change when it suits your purpose (such as grabbing the **left** field as if it were an object, and then resetting **left** as if it were a pointer).  Python makes this something of a quantum state: both wave and particle.

Disclaimer: you *will* eventually hit the ability to pass arguments with the familiar asterisk to grab the pointer to something, such as *my_list.  In that case, you *do* have a distinct difference ... but Python will collapse the wave function back to particle ASAP.  Don't worry about it for now, just know that it's coming later, so you don't lose faith in what you learned up to that point.

Comment: A good explanation, just got to ask, I thought self was a reference to the object, in this case self acts as a temporary "root"? Something else that bothers me is the argument self of delete, In my mind I thought that delete pretty much was redirecting the pointers, I dont know if this is correct to say. I just dont understand how it can redirect the pointers if I dont reveal which node I will remove with the remove-method in the binarytree class. Thanks a lot for the help everyone, feels like Im learning part by part for each day but I have a hard time understanding the pointers...

Comment: Delete doesn't redirect its parent's pointers.  Rather, it readjusts the tree of its descendants and passes that root back to **remove**, which performs the actual replacement.

Comment: Could you say that self acts as a sentinel-node before I give it a "real" root? And when you say left and right are implemented as object rerences aka pointers, would you say that self.left.right is the pointer to the grandchild of self or is it the grandchild, I have such a hard time understanding that

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Prune, that did help a lot!